# Why am I getting deadlock issue while inserting new records to same table from muliple thread,

Tags: java, sql-server

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
>
> atorg.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
>
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3356)
>
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3229)
>
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
>
> at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
>
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
>
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
>
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
>
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283)
>
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>
> at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
>
> at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
>
> at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
>
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532)
>
> ... 65 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 52) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1672)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:460)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:405)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:348)
>
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
>
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
>
> ... 83 common frames omitted

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please improve your question, as described in: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Kind regards...

Comment: Your update targets multiple records and some of them are already locked by the SELECT(s) each trhead are doing.

Answer (score 1):

**What are deadlocks?**

A deadlock occurs when 2 processes are competing for exclusive access to a resource but is unable to obtain exclusive access to it, because the other process is preventing it. This results in a standoff where neither process can proceed. The only way out of a deadlock is for one of the processes to be terminated. SQL Server automatically detects when deadlocks have occurred and takes action by killing one of the processes known as the victim.

**How they choose the victim?**

SQL Server chooses the process that has less work to rollback the process.

So, in your case, when you have more than one thread getting data from a specific table, they lock the table, and any process in the exact same time can't have access to it. In yor case, if you have any thread doing a SELECT to one table, and at the same time are trying to insert records in that table, can cause deadlock.

You can find out more here: [SQL Server deadlock](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-a-sql-server-deadlock/)

**How to prevent?**

You can add `with(nolock)` to your selects, example:

```
select * from table with(nolock)
```

If you want to add conditions, it should be like this:

```
select * from table with(nolock) where id = x
```

The bad thing is just if you do a select `with(nolock)` in the exact time that a transaction is doing some changes, you will catch them even if after that is made a rollback to the transaction.

You should also be aware of the effects of using `NOLOCK` including dirty reads, missing rows, reading rows twice, reading multiple versions of the same row, index corruption, and read errors. [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has a [great write up](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) on these effects.

More on DEADLOCKS and handling them:

- [Brent Ozar: Difficulty with DEADLOCKS](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/07/difficulty-deadlocks/)
- [Brent Ozar: sp_BlitzLock for Troubleshooting](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/introducing-sp_blitzlock-troubleshooting-sql-server-deadlocks/)
- [Red Gate: Handling Deadlocks](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/handling-deadlocks-in-sql-server/)
- [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer): Using it for [Troubleshooting Deadlocks](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/new-deadlock-visualizations-in-sql-sentry-and-plan-explorer)